# How to set ondragstart attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

The code creates an li element with the click of a button, but i would also like the li element to have an ondragstart attribute. How do i set ondragstart using Javascript?

```
const addListElement = function(){
  if (selected != null){
    const newListElement = document.createElement('li');
    newListElement.className = 'newLi';
    newListElement.textContent = 'textContent';
    newListElement.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
    newListElement.setAttribute('draggable', true);
    newListElement.setAttribute.ondragStart="myFunction(event)";
    selected.appendChild(newListElement);
    newListElement.addEventListener('click', selectElement);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Event Listener` to listen for the `dragstart` event:

```js
newListElement.addEventListener('dragstart', myFunction)
```

See [MDN Drag Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event#JavaScript).